# Some packages could not be installed

Tags: postfix, ssl

I'm trying to set up a mail server for a school project and I want to install postfix, When I ran `apt-get install postfix` an error occurs.

[image: terminal screenshot]

I've ran apt-get update upgrade as well before this also came up with a `NO_PUBKEY  16126d3a3e5c1192` error .

Results of `apt-cache policy ssl-cert postfix; lsb_release -a`:

```
ssl-cert:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:

postfix:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.11.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.11.0-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64
 Packages

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

`apt-get install ssl-cert`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ssl-cert is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ssl-cert' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy ssl-cert postfix; lsb_release -a`

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install ssl-cert` once again.

Comment: Add the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your NO_PUBKEY  problem

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126d3a3e5c1192
sudo apt-get update
```

And you don't have the `main` repository enabled

```
sudo apt-add-repository main
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

---

And if `software-properties-common` isn't installed (we need `apt-add-repository`)

```
cd
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.92.37.5_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i software-properties-common_0.92.37.5_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

---

Or use this `/etc/apt/sources.list` and don't forget to start

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
```

after **replacing** the content with the lines below

```
# See http://heus.archive.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty restricted universe main multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates restricted universe main multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-updates restricted universe main multiverse #Added by software-properties

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security restricted universe main multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security restricted universe main multiverse #Added by software-properties

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://us.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
# deb-src http://us.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner

deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main universe restricted multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-backports main universe restricted multiverse #Added by software-properties
```

Comment: gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found


and


apt-add is not a valid command

Comment: `sudo apt-add-repository main`

Comment: I am already in sudo su

Comment: Than without `sudo` :\ that makes no difference.

Comment: the error persists 

apt-add: command not found

Comment: ! `apt-add-repository main` !

Comment: http://oi58.tinypic.com/fz12sx.jpg

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: i ran wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/s/software-properties/software-properties-common_0.92.37.5_all.deb

the http request got a 404 not found error

Comment: You are offline or behind a proxy. Use the `sources.list` in my answer.

Comment: http://oi57.tinypic.com/2n823qu.jpg the're still errors. Thank you for taking your time to help me

Comment: Add the error messages into your question

Comment: And start a `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: i ran the above commands and tried to install postfix again, i got the packages have unmet dependencies, postfix : Depends: ssl-cert but it is not installable

Comment: Would an "archive update in progress" in the ubuntu source cause these problems? for example in http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ it says the archive is being updated

Comment: Where can I see this message?